# Test "should get index" throughs Undefined Method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

All,  I have the following models defined:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :users

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :name, uniqueness: true

end
```

And

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :abv, :first_name, :full_name, :last_name, :role_id

  has_many :defects
  belongs_to :role

  validates :first_name, :last_name, :full_name, :abv, :role_id, presence: true
  validates :full_name, :abv, uniqueness: true

end
```

I recently changed the view users 'index' to display user.role_id field to user.role.name to make the view more friendly!  This worked great! However when running rake test the users_controller_test through the following error:

1) Error:
test_should_get_index(UsersControllerTest):
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

After searching the blog I found references to erasing and recreating the test database worked for one individual, and changing the "should get index" test in the controller from

```
get :index
```

to
    get :index, :user.role_id => 1  #forced to known value

But nothing that I have done has corrected the test failure.  What am I missing here, could this be an issue with how the data in the test fixtures is defined, or am I missing a core rails concept?

As always, Thanks in advance,

Richard

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with associations, you can fix this by defining a reference node between two different fixtures.